# Cascading merges in Bitbucket Cloud

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

My company has Bitbucket Cloud (not Bitbucket Server) and we want to start using branching exclusively for development.

One of the things I was looking forward to was automatic merging (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html) but I noticed that this seems to only be available to Bitbucket Server not Bitbucket Cloud.

Is there any way to get similar functionality with Bitbucket Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is No, see bitbucket issue [14286](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14286/automatic-branch-merging-for-bitbucket)